# Add a navigation bar in the app delegates

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a problem in my appdelegate. I want to add a navigation bar, but it doesn't work.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

    UniversViewController *universViewController = [[UniversViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ProduitsListinTableViewController" bundle:nil];
    universViewController.title = @"univers";

    CategoriesViewController *categoriesViewController = [[CategoriesViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ProduitsListinTableViewController" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:categoriesViewController];
    navigationController.title = @"categories";
    [navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];

    ProduitsListinTableViewController *produitListe = [[ProduitsListinTableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ProduitsListinTableViewController" bundle:nil];
    produitListe.title = @"troisième";

    _tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:universViewController, categoriesViewController, produitListe, nil];

    [self.window setRootViewController:_tabBarController];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Do I have to add something in `UniversViewController`, `CategoriesViewController` and `ProduitsListinTableViewController` or this is directly in the appdelegate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];

    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    UIViewController *viewController1, *viewController2,*viewController3,*viewController4,*viewController5;

    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    {

        viewController1 = [[[HomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomeViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];

        navController=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController1];

        viewController2 = [[[SearchViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SearchViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];

        navController2=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController2];

        viewController3 = [[[LocationsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LocationsViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];

        navController3=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController3];

        viewController4 = [[[CallViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CallViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];

        navController4=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController4];

        viewController5 = [[[MyBookingsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyBookingsViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];

        navController5=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController5];


    }

    self.tabBarController = [[[UITabBarController alloc] init] autorelease];

    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:navController,navController2,navController3,navController4,navController5,nil];

    //self.window.rootViewController =self.navController;

    self.window.rootViewController=self.tabBarController;

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you, this is perfect and it works! I added viewController1.title = @"TITLE"; so the title appear directly. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

I always follow this approach when I have both a UINavigationController and a UITabbarController:
You need to start with a view based application. And then create a UITabbarController in your appDelegate file.

```
Appdelegate.h

UITabBarController *tabBarController;
// set properties

Appdelegate.m

// Synthesize

tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
tabBarController.delegate=self;

// Adding Search,Nearby,Map,AboutUs,Favorites Tabs to tabBarController  
Search * search = [[Search alloc] init];  
UINavigationController *searchNav = [[UINavigationController alloc]        initWithRootViewController:search];  

Nearby* nearby = [[Nearby alloc] init];  
UINavigationController *nearbyNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:nearby];  

Map* map = [[Map alloc] init];  
UINavigationController *mapNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:map];  

AboutUs* aboutUs = [[AboutUs alloc] init];  
UINavigationController *aboutUsNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:aboutUs];  

Favorites* favorites = [[Favorites alloc] init];  
UINavigationController *favoritesNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:favorites];  

NSArray* controllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:searchNav,nearbyNav,mapNav,aboutUsNav,favoritesNav, nil];  
tabBarController.viewControllers = controllers; 

[window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
```

You can accordingly manage in which tab you want to place navigation controller or only a view controller.

Then in each of the view controllers mentioned above you need to implement

```
- (id)init {}
```

in which you can set Tab name and image.

I always follow this approach and it never fails.  The tabs are always visible.  You can make changes according to your code.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for you message. I tried but it didn't work. I think i did something wrong.. But the post bellow worked for me.